# Insert tab-delimited values into database

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a `tab-delimited txt file` with rows separated by tabs, and rows separated by newlines. This is what it actually looks like:

`476502291\t\tLF3139812164\t\tTitle 1\tKids & Family\nGRAV_2011\t\tThe Full Picture\tIndependent\n [...etc...]`

Note that sometimes values are separated by two tabs instead of one.

I need to insert this into a mysql table, which should result in the following:

```
ID             title               genre
476502291      Title 1             Kids & Family
GRAV_2011      The Full Picture    Independent
```

How would I read a tab-separated txt file and run a `for` loop in order to insert values into a table named `vendor` using MySQLdb?

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",
                             user = "me",
                             passwd = "password",
                             db = "my-db")
>>> cursor = conn.cursor ()
>>> # for loop  # how to read from the txt file to insert it as required?
>>>     # cursor.execute (INSERT...)
>>> conn.commit()
>>> conn.close()
```

Comment: "mainly am having trouble doing the for loop"  What trouble?  Commit usually goes last after all the work is done.  Is that your question?  Where to commit?  Or do you want to know how to read a CSV-file with tab separators?  Have you read the Python `csv` module yet?

Comment: thank you for the response. the latter.

Comment: Are there any blank fields? That is, is `\t\t` always equivalent to `\t`, or does `\t\t` sometimes mean "separator, blank field, separator"?

Comment: @David542: Thanks aren't appropriate.  What's appropriate is an **update** to the question to clarify it.  Adding comments doesn't help.  Fixing the question helps.

Comment: It actually means blank field, but it is **always** a blank field, so it can be ignored (i.e., my db doesn't include that column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1.  Read the `csv` module.  http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html.  This does what you want.

```
with open('your_data_file.dat','r') as source:
    rdr= csv.reader( source, delimiter='\t', quotechar='')
    for row in rdr:
        # you have your columns with which to do your insert.
conn.commit()
```

Step 2.  Read up on context managers, also.

```
from contextlib import closing

with open('your_data_file.dat','r') as source:
    rdr= csv.reader( source, delimiter='\t', quotechar='')
    with closing(conn.cursor()) as cursor:
        for row in rdr:
            # you have your columns with which to do your insert.
conn.commit()
```

This will assure that cursors and files are properly closed.

Answer (score 1):

As long as tabs are only used as delimiters in your file you should be able to do something like this:

```
import re

# connect to MySQLdb

with open(file_name) as f:
    for line in f:
        id, title, genre = re.split(r'\t+', line)
        # execute INSERT statement
```

The idea is that you will always have two groups of tabs, one between ID and title, and the other between title and genre.  By using `re.split()` on `\t+` (one or more tabs) you will get a list of length 3 with the fields you are interested in.

If there are any lines in your file that do not match this format you should add some additional checking, maybe something along the lines of `data = re.split(r'\t+', line)` and `if len(data) == 3:` before the tuple unpacking.

**edit:**  This solution goes with the assumption that you do not have blank fields, so if it is legal for a line to have just an ID and a genre but no title this will not work.  It will still work if you can have a title but no ID or genre as long as there are are leading tabs when ID is missing and trailing tabs when genre is missing.

Answer (score 0):

import reg

## connect to MySQLdb

with open(file_name) as f:
    for line in f:
        id, title, genre = re.split(r'\t+', line)
        # execute INSERT statement